# Is it possible to send SMS via WIFI on android?

Tags: android, sms, server, sms-gateway

Hi I would like to know if it is possible to send SMS via WIFI on android? 
and If it is possible, will charges be applied to the sender and also the receiver?

Are there any alternatives to send free SMS to users and charges will not be applied to the receiver?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

SMS as it is can be sent only by GSM network. The alternative is to ask some device by the internet to send SMS by GSM. That's how SMS getaways work. I'm not sure if there are any free SMS getaways, but there are alot of paid ones.
One more option is not to use SMS at all. If both - target device and source device have internet connection, you may use PUSH notifications to deliver messages from one device to another.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I am create an application whereby the receiver will still be able to receive the message eventhough they do not have a smart phone (using a normal old phone) or internet. And if I were to use a paid version of SMS gateway to send sms to a list of users, will the receiver be charged ? and also will the sender be charged twice whereby one is its own carrier and the other is the sms gateway that I am using?

Comment: @AuroraBlaze, the first question is No(I'm sure). Th receiver woun't be charged. At least it is normal behavior not to charge receivers. Didn't understood the second question, but I'm sure that you'd better ask the SMS getaway provider's support about it once you select the provider. Unfortunately I can't suggest you any good providers because I don't use it myself, just have such a thing integrated with the web platform I'm developing android client for.

Comment: Regarding the second question, I am just wondering that, If I am already paying for a sms gateway to send sms, will the provider/carrier still charge me for it?

Comment: @AuroraBlaze, no, it shouldn't normally. But anyway you should carefully read those details in the getaway provider's documentation